# A series with prime numbers and fractional parts

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

Considering $p_{n}$ the nth prime number, then compute the limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left\{ \dfrac{1}{p_{1}} + \frac{1}{p_{2}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{p_{n}} \right\} - \{\log{\log n } \}$$
where $\{ x \}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$.

Comment: Do you know that the series diverges like $\log \log n$, for starters? That is $$\sum_{n=1}^n \frac 1 {p_n} \sim \log \log n$$

Comment: @PeterTamaroff That doesn't really help though. It doesn't even show existence of the limit, e.g. $2^n$ diverges like $2^n+n$.

Comment: The limit does exist. However, to get an estimate of the limit you need to prove prime number theorem i.e. for this case we need to prove that $\psi(x) \sim x$.

Comment: @AlexBecker I'm talking about $o(1)$ here.

Answer (score 3):

In [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes) under Third it is stated that without the fractional part signs the limit is the Meissel–Mertens constant, about $0.261497$.  There must be many $n$ for which the first term is greater than some natural and the second term is less than the same and many other $n$ where they are between the same pair of naturals.  In the first case the value will be about $0.261497-1$, in the second it will be about $0.261497$, so the limit will not exist.

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means a complete answer but a sketch on how to possibly go about. To get the constant, you need some careful computations.

First get an asymptotic for $ \displaystyle \sum_{n \leq x} \dfrac{\Lambda(n)}{n}$ as $\log(x) - 2 + o(1)$.

To get this asymptotic, you need Stirling's formula and the fact that $\psi(x) = x + o(x)$ i.e. the PNT.

Then relate $ \displaystyle \sum_{\overset{p \leq x}{p- \text{prime}}} \dfrac{\Lambda(p)}{p}$ to $ \displaystyle \sum_{n \leq x} \dfrac{\Lambda(n)}{n}$. Essentially, you can get $$ \displaystyle \sum_{\overset{p \leq x}{p- \text{prime}}} \dfrac{\Lambda(p)}{p} = \displaystyle \sum_{n \leq x} \dfrac{\Lambda(n)}{n} + C + o(1)$$
Getting this constant $C$ is also hard. You can try your luck with partial summation.

Then relate $ \displaystyle \sum_{\overset{p \leq x}{p- \text{prime}}} \dfrac1{p}$ to $\displaystyle \sum_{\overset{p \leq x}{p- \text{prime}}} \dfrac{\Lambda(p)}{p}$ i.e. $\displaystyle \sum_{\overset{p \leq x}{p- \text{prime}}} \dfrac{\log(p)}{p}$ by partial summation to get $$\displaystyle \sum_{\overset{p \leq x}{p- \text{prime}}} \dfrac1{p} = \log(\log(x)) + C_1 + o(1)$$
You might need to invoke PNT here as well. The $C_1$ here obviously depends on he constant $C$ and constant $2$ before.

<s>**EDIT** Thinking about it there might be a way to avoid PNT to get the constant.</s>

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the asymptotic for $\sum 1/p$ was proved by Mertens long before PNT, including (miraculously) the constant.

Comment: @ErickWong So the PNT is not needed in finding the constant?

Comment: Correct, although if memory serves it relies on some miraculous identities and/or surprising cancellations.  Oh, this [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0504289v3.pdf) by Mark Villarino discusses Mertens's original proof, very nice!